# Pentaho Kettle (PDI) Split Names

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

How can I split a name into FirstName and LastName?

There is a Split Fields transformation function but that only splits the fields by a given delimiter. That would have worked except for the fact that in some cases the data will have 3 names, or even four names. So there is no dynamic way of getting the last name if you don't know how many names are to be supplied.

Assume the input field FullName with the following 4 rows:

`John Doe
John Doe Smith
John Doe Smith Jackson
John`

The split should be by space character, and the output should be:
For all the 4 rows, the FirstName should be John (obviously)

But the LastName output should be:

`Doe
Smith
Jackson
<null>`

If there comes a requirement for MiddleName (not urgent but would be good for information purposes), the output would be:

`<null>
Doe
Not Sure - may have to clarify with client if that comes up
<null>`

Comment: So you want the last name of a set of names seperated by a delimiter to the *Last Name* and all other names concatenated to be the *First Name*?

Comment: Could you modify your question to include the more detailed requirement? The comments are not suited for row oriented formatting.

Comment: It's a little clearer now. So, what shall happen in the case of four names or more?

Comment: Updated to include such a scenario. Basically, it's first and last names, no matter how many they are

Comment: As much as I dislike breaking the visual metaphor, I'd probably use a `Modified Javascript Value` step for this. You might get it to work with a `Split Fields to rows` step, a `Sequence generator` and an `Analytic Query` step, but that makes for a messy transform.

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This task can be solved by using the **regex evaluation** component with regular expression

```
^([^ ]+).*?([^ ]+)?$
```

The first group `([^ ]+)` always picks the first name in a string because of the `^` at the beginning. The optional second group `([^ ]+)?` picks the last name in the string because of the `$` at the end. The expression `.*?` picks anything in between (including the empty string). Note that it must be made lazy (using the '?') so that it does not steal characters from the optional second group which is lazy because of the `?`, too.

The test transformation looks like this

[image: Test Transformation]

The details of the regular expression component look like this

[image: Details of the Regular Expression Component]

Note that the string containing the full name **must not** have leading or trailing spaces in it. The *string operations* component **Trim String** takes care of that.